# How do I write to get the value of one document from one reference using firestore in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

How do I write to get the value of one document from one reference using firestore in Angular?

There are two collections in the root, and one collection is connected by reference by id.(digitalID (reference)).

```
users (collection)
 |-- userid (document)
       |-- name
       |-- digitalID (reference)

digitalContents (collection)
 |-- digitalID (document)
       |-- name
       |-- price
```

I could not take the value even if I went as follows.

```
constructor(public auth: AuthService, private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const user = this.auth.currentUser;

    this.selectedContentsPrice = this.afs.collection<User>(`users/${user.userid}/digitalID`).valueChanges().subscribe(data => data.price);
    console.log(this.selectedContentsPrice)
```

How can I get the value of the collection connected from one reference?
ex)digitalContents's price

Comment: The issue is that even though the data structure on your side is as if it is referencing on firestore it is not referencing. It is only saving the ID, what you can do is to get this in two queries, the first one to get the digitalID document key and the second to change its value

Comment: `users / $ {user.userid} / digitalID`
Isn't this writing a reference?

Comment: the thing is that you need to get that value in order to use it, this is why it needs two queries.